# Download the APEX site completely

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

On an Apex page I have 3 reports and 1 diagram. Can I download all of this with one example? as a screenshot or completely in a CSV (without the diagram)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking whether you can download result of those reports, then Apex allows you to use e.g. "Actions" button (in **Interactive Report**) with the "Download" option which offers CSV. Though, you'll have to do it report-by-report.

If it is a **Classic Report**, you have to enable CSV export in region's "Attributes" section.

---

If you are talking about exporting the whole application (so that you could move it to another database/workspace), then use "Export/Import" option within the App Builder.

Comment: I think I understand. If I have several Classic Reports in one region, I can download them together. Otherwise I can only do this individually via the corresponding action?

Comment: I don't think that you can download them together ... those "actions" (downloading) is related to each region, separately.